# iOS: stream to rtmp server from GPUImage

Tags: rtmp, gpuimage

Is it possible to stream video and audio to a rtmp://-server with GPUImage?

I'm using the `GPUImageVideoCamera` and would love to stream (video + audio) directly to a rtmp-server.

I tried [VideoCore](https://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore) which streams perfectly to e.g. YouTube, but whenever I try to overlay the video with different images I do get performance problems.

It seems as GPUImage is doing a really great job there, but I don't know how to stream with that. I found [issues](https://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore/issues/216) on VideoCore talking about feeding VideoCore with GPUImage, but I don't have a starting point on how that's implemented...

Comment: did you end up using GPUImage and if so did it work? I am myself exploring my options right now!